# React + Typescript object props to component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Simple case; I'm rendering a list of 'Reviews'. These are provided using the following Proptype:

```
export interface Props {
    title: string;
    name: string;
    reviewdesc: string;
    rating: number;
}
```

Mapping through the results in the parent component:

```
{reviews.map((review: Props) => {
    return <Review data={review} />;
})}
```

And using the same Proptypes in the child component:

```
const Review = (data: Props) => { ...
```

It is giving me this error:

```
Type '{ data: Props; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
```

It feels like I'm forgetting a little thing. I thought I should catch the Props like `{data}` in the child component, but it gives:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Props'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing props incorrectly. Use,

```
<Review { ...review } />
```

`...` is called the [spread](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) operator and it "spreads" the properties of your object into props for that element.

Comment: Never knew this syntax. Thank you so much!